# Разные APK для разных языков

Tags: android, google-play

Искал в справочной Google Play Developer, так и не нашел.
Можно ли добавить APK для каждого языка в Google Play Developer Console?
И если можно, что нужно сделать, чтобы добавить их.

Comment: Зачем разные APK, когда есть такое понятие как интернационализация в Android? Пак ресурсов сильно тяжёлый получается? Подгружайте ресурсы извне при установке приложения и всё. (Вспомните игры, которые требуют "доустановки", например").

Comment: а зачем? если поддержку нескольких языков и даже диалектов можно реализовать в самом приложении в одном APK

Comment: Мне кажется, вы пытаетесь решить свою проблему костылем. В чем именно проблема? Я так понимаю, разные АПК для разных языков - это ваше решение какой-то проблемы?

Comment: @metalurgus. У меня есть база данных и код приложения естественно работает с этой базой данных, но если переводить на другой язык, столбцов в таблице базы данных могут быть или меньше или больше в зависимости от языка. И из-за этого я хотел бы, создать приложение отдельно для языка.

Comment: @Iman а как связан язык и количество столбцов в БД? И насколько отличаться будет? Может есть смысл сделать по максимальному количеству и пусть они пустыми будут.

Comment: @DimXenon можешь ли привести примеры подгружения ресурсов при установке приложения, Мне нужно чисто текст подгрузить для своего языка

Comment: Не при установке, а непосредственно при первом запуске. Для примера посмотрите японские игры-тамагочи де кошек или собак выращивают, или какую-нибудь мобильную RPG.